# new to android, Java syntax is not clear: data.setSelected(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());

Tags: java, android

I was going through [this tutorial](http://schimpf.es/listview-with-checkboxes-inside/) and came across this code at the very end:

```
data.setSelected(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
```

The part which is confusing is the (((CheckBox) view).  , i have no idea what all these brackets mean. I went through some Java documentation but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down:

```
((CheckBox) view)
```

Anytime you see `(SomeClass) someObject` this is an attempt to cast that object to that class. `view`'s class does not extend CheckBox in this case so w try to force that. If that can't be done a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

From there, we call `isChecked()` on that object and pass that as a parameter to `data.setSelected`. We can write this as follows:

```
CheckBox myCheckbox = (CheckBox) view; //cast
// CheckBox myCheckbox = view // would likely not work
boolean checkboxIsChecked = myCheckbox.isChecked();
data.setSelected(checkboxIsChecked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go paren by paren.

first, `(CheckBox)` is a typecast.  This means that regardless of the type of the object next to it (in this case `view`), we will treat it as a `CheckBox`.

Next, `((CheckBox) view)`.  This is a way of wrapping the previous statement so that the compiler will see the whole entity as a `CheckBox`.  This allows us to call methods from it that belong to `CheckBox`, in this case `isChecked()`.

Finally, the outermost set of parenthesis wrap our previous statement, `((CheckBox) view).isChecked()` as the argument of `setSelected()`.

Answer (score 1):

> i have no idea what all these brackets mean. I went through some Java
>   documentation but could not find anything.

This:

```
((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
```

This is explicit casting (it assumes that view is instance of CheckBox). 
If view is instance of CheckBox it will be explicitly casted into CheckBox and since this view will be CheckBox and you can use it like CheckBox - use specific methods etc.

If view isn't instance of CheckBox, ClassCastException will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets in question are used to logically group code so that certain conditions are met before others during the execution of the expression. In your example:

```
data.setSelected(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
```

can be rewritten (very verbosely as):

```
// Cast the view object as a CheckBox object
Checkbox myCheckbox = (CheckBox)view;

// get checked status of myCheckbox
boolean checkboxChecked = myCheckbox.isChecked();

// Set selected based on if it's checked
data.setSelected(checkboxChecked);
```

So if you look at the original example again (with additional spaces) `( (CheckBox) view ) .isChecked()` you can see that the inside is the casting `view` to a `CheckBox` and that is wrapped with parenthesis which causes it to be executed before the `isChecked()` method call which ensures that it will be called on a variable of type `CheckBox`.